# libxml/xmlversion.h missing on FreeNAS / TrueNAS / FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, libxml2

I have a working C application that I'm trying to port to FreeNAS-11.3-U5.  It relies on the libxml2 libraries to do XML processing.

In my FreeNAS Jail, I have successfully installed libxml2 (sudo pkg install libxml2) but I get this error when trying to install the development package:

```
sudo pkg install libxml2-dev
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'libxml2-dev' have been found in the repositories
```

Searches for combinations of FreeNAS, TrueNAS, FreeBSD with libxml2-dev have not been fruitful (maybe partially because Google likes to drop that hyphen).  I don't see an option to develop from scratch.  Any ideas how I can get or emulate that package on FreeNAS 11?

Thanks

Comment: If the only difference between libxml2 and -dev is memory debugging, there is an option in ports to turn that on.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought the libxml2-dev package also included all the header files, while the libxml2 package does not.  The real problem I'm trying to chase, is that I get this error during compile on FreeNAS; any idea how to solve it?  "fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory"  (I'll change the question title; this is a dramatic turn of direction.)